# Jmeter data Correlation for different items

Tags: jmeter

I am recording a food ordering website in jmeter,flow is 1.launch 2.take away 3. select meal 1 4.select meal 2 5.select meal 3 6.add to cart  7.order details 8.payment.I want different meal selection but when i correlate product id and category id , every time the meal selected are same. Where am i wrong?

Answer (score -1):

As per your explanation, i could understand that the Product ID and Category ID are not dynamic. It should have been predefined for each and every meal. So you are capturing the same value and using, so you are able to see the same meal selected for every run

Comment: ok thank you . I got that . But what should i do to select different meals.

Comment: Change the product ID and Category ID for the meal you want to select. Use parameters for that

Comment: i parameterised both the values , and script is working now . Thank you